# How to preserve EXIF data in Jimp when compressing it or using the cover function?

Tags: node.js, image, image-processing

I tried to use **Jimp** as a library to compress the images uploaded to my server. However, even when the image is rotated in my computer, when i upload it to jimp, i guess it doesn't process the exif orientation data and saves the non-rotated picture after compressing it.

```
image.exifRotate();
```

However, i found this method in jimp, but seems its not having any effect?
Any suggestion how to overcome it ?

Comment: You might be running in the wrong jimp instance. I tested in a project I'm working and it's working. `const img = await jimp.read('url');`, `await img.exifRotate();`

Comment: Yes, i got it working... :-)

Comment: I'm getting `image.exifRotate is not a function`, and it's not in the docs at https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp , how do we do this in in 2020?

Comment: Same here in 2021 - Any known solution? @BartS

Comment: `exifRotate` is gone from the docs too and nothing about EXIF there...

Comment: I think I ended up using another npm package called `jpeg-autorotate`